# Laravel 5.1, Return response to user, then excute some code

Tags: php, android, laravel, google-cloud-messaging, laravel-5

**The Story**

I am using NotificationPusher that uses GCM to send notification to user.
It takes some time to connect to google server and wait for response.

***So,*** I don't want my user to wait until notification is sent, I want him to get the response (say that he successfully commented on a post). 
Then, -After response- the notification is sent to the user whom post is commented on.

How to do that, I am getting **crazy**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use queue. When user comment post, add event to queue.
Queue is parsed by cron (using Laravel's command).